# How to add one plugin to multiple pages at once in typo3 and tell which action to use

Tags: plugins, typo3, typoscript, typo3-11.x

I have a typo3 installation with one extension that has a plugin.

I want to add the plugin to one page via typoscript and all subpages in that page tree should have it as well.
I only find code fragments that use **switchableControllerActions** but this is deprecated, as far as I can see.

How can I tell the plugin in the page which action is the action to use?

Comment: Please post snippets of your [plugin configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/11.5/en-us/4-FirstExtension/7-configuring-the-plugin.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These fragments handling `switchableControllerActions` can be ignored if you have already separated plugins in your extension.

```
lib.insertPlugin = USER
lib.insertPlugin {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  vendorName = myVendor
  pluginName = MyPlugin
  extensionName = MyExtension

  settings =< plugin.tx_myExtension.settings
  persistence =< plugin.tx_myExtension.persistence
  view =< plugin.tx_myExtension.view

  settings {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The plugin will use its default action (except, there is another action defined in the request, e.g. by submitting a form, following a link,...).

The first action in the action list of the first line of the configuration parameter is the default action of the plugin. (-> `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin()`)